# Rails Active Admin when I create my form it only displays the last field. Permit params wont accept :page field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, activeadmin, formtastic

I am having 2 problems.

1) formtastic will only show the last input field instead of all of them. In this case it will only display:

```
          r.input :sort_order
```

2)  I had to do some wierd wrap f.inputs around each field to get it to show up which i believe is the wrong way. But when i submit the form it says Unpermitted parameters: page.  When I did clearly define page I dont know how else to get permit params accept this.

Here is my model

```
    class Fact < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_one :page, as: :pageable, dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :page
    end
```

The other model:

```
    class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to  :pageable, polymorphic: true
    end
```

My active admin:

```
    ActiveAdmin.register Fact do
      permit_params :id, page_attributes: [:type, :name,  :description :sort_order ] 

      form do |f|
        f.inputs "My Page", for: [:page,       f.object.page || Page.new] do |r|
          r.input :name
          r.input :description
          r.input :sort_order
        end  
      end
    end
```

Comment: I found the first problem. I had to pass id to the page_attributes.  But still not sure how to get formtastic to show all the fields.  It will only show the last one. I want them all on separate lines because i want to be able to add other options t them.

Comment: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3579 , is already fixed